# Mathematical Analysis

Tags: real-analysis

A function $f$ is such that its second derivative is continuous on $[a,a+h]$ and differentiable on $(a,a+h)$. Show there exists $c \in(0,1) $ such that $$f(a+h)-f(a)-\frac{1}{2} h(f'(a)+f'(a+h))+ \frac{h^3}{12}f'''(a+ch) =0$$

I tried to define a similar function on $[0,1]$ and use Mean Value theorem to get the above equality to no avail. Could anyone advise?

Comment: I think is $f'''(a+ch)$ not $f''(a+ch)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

we have

let $f(x)$ is such that its three derivative is continuous on $[a,b]$,then exsit $c\in(a,b)$ such that
$$f(b)-f(a)-\dfrac{1}{2}[f'(a)+f'(b)]+\dfrac{f'''(c)}{12}(b-a)^3=0$$

**Proof**
let 
$$12\dfrac{f(a)-f(b)+\dfrac{b-a}{2}(f'(a)+f'(b))}{(b-a)^3}=A$$

we let
$$F(x)=f(x)-f(b)+\dfrac{b-x}{2}[f'(x)+f'(b)]-\dfrac{A}{12}(b-x)^3$$
then
$$\Longrightarrow F(a)=F(b)=0\Longrightarrow F'(\xi_{1})=0,\xi_{1}\in(a,b)$$

since
$$F'(x)=f'(x)-\dfrac{f'(x)+f'(b)}{2}+\dfrac{b-x}{2}f''(x)+\dfrac{A}{4}(b-x)^2$$
so
$$F'(b)=0\Longrightarrow F''(c)=0,c\in(\xi_{1},b)$$

since
$$F''(x)=f''(x)-\dfrac{f''(x)}{2}-\dfrac{f''(x)}{2}+\dfrac{b-x}{2}f'''(x)-\dfrac{A}{2}(b-x)=\dfrac{1}{2}(b-x)[f'''(x)-A]$$
so $$A=f'''(c)$$